# laravel remove /public/ from url and when calling css and javascript

Tags: laravel

most of us know how to remove `/public/` from url by:

1. Rename the server.php in the your Laravel root folder to index.php
2. copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder

but i still have to add `/public/` each time i tried to call `css` or `js` file

/public/js/file.js

/public/css/file.css

Comment: Yes. and  you forgot to question?

Comment: You need to move the root to public... doing what you are doing is not very safe as you are storing all of your system files in a public directory...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your apache or Nginx configuration? A simplified virtual server definition in httpd_vhosts.conf for apache looks like that...:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localtest.com
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/localtest/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

This is how I redirect the root for localtest.com to the public directory. In this case the localtest directory contains the laravel app... but is not directly accessible through localtest.com.

Hope this helps.